# jQuery redirect to source url

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I would like to redirect a user to a target URL on a button click. The target URL is variable and has to be read from the current page URL parameter 'source':

For instance, I have a url http://w/_l/R/C.aspx?source=http://www.google.com

When the user clicks on a button he's being redirect to http://www.google.com

How would I do that with jQuery?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all you need to get the url param : source 
this can be done with a function like :

```
function GetParam(name) {
    return decodeURI(
        (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(location.search)||[,null])[1]
    );
} 

// you can use it like 
var source = GetParam('source');
//then
window.location.href = source
```

Answer (score 0):

On button click handler, just write window.location.href = http://www.google.com

Comment: -1 as it is obvious that the OP needs to redirect to the URL defined in the URL parameter 'source'.

Answer (score 0):

get url params : (copied from another stackoverflow question) :

```
var params= {};

document.location.search.replace(/\??(?:([^=]+)=([^&]*)&?)/g, function () {
    function decode(s) {
        return decodeURIComponent(s.split("+").join(" "));
    }

    params[decode(arguments[1])] = decode(arguments[2]);
});

window.location = params['source'];
```

Comment: $_GET is not a traditionally accepted name for a Javascript variable. That's how request parameter map is called in PHP, but it may be a bit misleading here.

Comment: I just did not want to alter the source where I got it ()I will change it now

Answer (score 0):

You will need to parse the query string to get the value of the variable source.
You don't need jQuery for it.

A simple function like this will suffice:

```
function getFromQueryString(ji) {
    hu = window.location.search.substring(1);
    gy = hu.split("&");
    for (i = 0; i < gy.length; i++) {
        ft = gy[i].split("=");
        if (ft[0] == ji) {
            return ft[1];
        }
    }
}

location.href = getFromQueryString("source");
```

Comment: No, it does not. It is only splitting the query string, checking for the GET parameter you are looking for("source" in this example), and returning the appropriate value.

Answer (score 0):

Using the url parsing code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-query-string-values-in-javascript) use this to parse your url (this should be included once in your document):

```
var urlParams = {};
(function () {
    var e,
        a = /\+/g,  // Regex for replacing addition symbol with a space
        r = /([^&=]+)=?([^&]*)/g,
        d = function (s) { return decodeURIComponent(s.replace(a, " ")); },
        q = window.location.search.substring(1);

    while (e = r.exec(q))
       urlParams[d(e[1])] = d(e[2]);
})();
```

Then do this to redirect to the source parameter:

```
window.location.href = urlParams["source"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the jQuery framework, I'd make use of the [jQuery URL Parser plugin](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser), which safely parses and decodes URL parameters, fragment...

You can use it like this:

```
var source = $.url().param('source');
window.location.href = source;
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this,

```
<a id="linkId" href=" http://w/_l/R/C.aspx?source=http://www.google.com">Click me</a>


$('#linkId').click(function(e){
  var href=$(this).attr('href');
  var url=href.substr(href.indexof('?'))
  window.location =url;
  return false;   

});
```

Comment: -1 This won't work as @Stefan stated. This is not a proper way of reading URL parameters.